# How to deal with optim when some parameters become known?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I have faced a problem with passing arguments to `optim`.
Suppose I want to do box constraint minimization on a multivariate function, for example

```
fr <- function(x) {   ## Rosenbrock  function
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  x3 <- x[3]
  x4 <- x[4]
  100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2 +
  100 * (x3 - x2 * x2)^2 + (1 - x2)^2 +
  100 * (x4 - x3 * x3)^2 + (1 - x3)^2
}
```

As usual `optim` can be used as following:

```
optim(par = c(0, 1, 1, 2), fr, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0, 0, 0, 0), upper = c(3, 3, 3, 3))
```

Now, suppose this procedure repeated in an algorithm which changes `lower` and `upper` (box constraints), followed by `par`, such that in some iterations one, two or three value of  parameters become known, for example `x1` = 1. in this case I expect `optim` to handle this by setting the initial value, lower and upper bounds of `x1` to 1:

```
optim(par = c(1, 1, 1, 2), fr, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(1, 0, 0, 0), upper =    c(1, 3, 3, 3))
```

But by runnig this line I got an error:

```
Error in optim(par = c(1, 1, 1, 2), fr, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(1,  : non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

Now, the question is how can I deal with this feature of `optim` without defining many new functions when one or some of the parameters become known?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like `optim` is not able to handle the upper and lower matching. I suppose you could parameterize your function with the known values and use some simple `ifelse` statements to check if you should be using the passed value from `optim` or the known value:

```
# Slightly redefined function to optimize
fr2 <- function(opt.x, known.x) {
  x <- ifelse(is.na(known.x), opt.x, known.x)
  100 * (x[2] - x[1] * x[1])^2 + (1 - x[1])^2 +
  100 * (x[3] - x[2] * x[2])^2 + (1 - x[2])^2 +
  100 * (x[4] - x[3] * x[3])^2 + (1 - x[3])^2
}

# Optimize, and then replace the appropriate indices of the result with known vals
known.x <- c(NA, 1, NA, 1)
opt.result <- optim(par = c(0, 1, 1, 2), fr2, method = "L-BFGS-B",
                    lower = c(0, 0, 0, 0), upper = c(3, 3, 3, 3), known.x=known.x)
opt.result$par <- ifelse(is.na(known.x), opt.result$par, known.x)
opt.result
# $par
# [1] 0.9999995 1.0000000 0.9999996 1.0000000
# 
# $value
# [1] 1.795791e-10
# 
# $counts
# function gradient 
#       13       13 
# 
# $convergence
# [1] 0
# 
# $message
# [1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

This code basically ignores the indices passed from `optim` if they are already known, and just uses the known values in those cases.

Comment: nice trick. In fact, you used the ellipsis (...) in optim which pass further arguments to fn and gr. this simple feature make optim flexible. I have not paid attention to it before, thank you